# Why do we need fields for pre-, in- and post-order traversals in a Binary Tree subclass?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am self-learning Binary Tree-related content using the Open Data Structure Textbook on line.

However, I am working through the excercises I came to one which I really have no idea what it is asking. Take a look at [Exercise 6.7 in ODS](https://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/6_3_Discussion_Exercises.html), which reads:

> **Exercise 6..7**   Create a subclass of `BinaryTree` whose nodes have fields for storing pre-order, post-order, and in-order numbers. Write recursive methods `preOrderNumber()`, `inOrderNumber()`, and `postOrderNumbers()` that assign these numbers correctly. These methods should each run in O(n) time.

I am not asking for a solution here, I am just having a hard time understanding what the author of the textbook is asking to do for this particular exercise. In my opinion, pre-order, in-order or post-order should be used for traversal, so what is the purpose of keeping a field to store numbers? And I am actually confused about what numbers he is referring to as well.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the author is interested in having you create classes like:

```
class LabeledBinaryTree extends BinaryTree {
    void preOrderNumber();
    void inOrderNumber();
    void postOrderNumber();
}
```

and

```
class LabeledNode<T> extends Node<T> {
    T data;
    LabeledNode<T> left;
    LabeledNode<T> right;
    int preOrderNum;
    int inOrderNum;
    int postOrderNum;

    public LabeledNode(T data, LabeledNode<T> left, LabeledNode<T> right);
}
```

The point of this is related to subsequent challenges that ask you to use the populated values for the ordering numbers to solve higher-level problems efficiently, like

> Given a node `u`, determine the depth of `u`.

Normally, solving this problem would require traversing the tree from the root to `u` which is O(n) time complexity. But the author explains that, given a pre-processed `LabeledNode`, it's possible to infer the depth of the node `u` in O(1) time using the three fields (`preOrderNum`, `inOrderNum` and `postOrderNum`).

As for the numbers themselves, they indicate the node's position in the stated traversal. For example, if we have a tree like:

```
   [A]
  /   \
[B]   [C]
        \
        [D]
```

After running the methods from the `LabeledBinaryTree` class, we get:

```
           [A pre=0,in=1,post=3]
              /              \
[B pre=1,in=0,post=0] [C pre=2,in=2,post=2]
                               \
                         [D pre=3,in=3,post=1]
```

Because the traversals are

```
pre  => [A, B, C, D]
in   => [B, A, C, D]
post => [B, D, C, A]
```

For additional clarification, check the [description and diagram](https://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/6_3_Discussion_Exercises.html#fig:binarytree-numbering) above the question you posed.

Comment: Thank you, now I am much clearer of the usage of this instance variable!